# uninitialized constant ActionController (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting this error when trying to deploy.

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/hello_app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant ActionController (NameError)
```

application_controller.rb

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def hello
    render text: "hello, world!"
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'application#hello'
```

I am using Cloud9.

Please help me, I wonder "ActionController::Base" spells miss. But this is correct...

Comment: What version of rails do you have?

Comment: How are you running Rails? Are you sure `rails` is in your `Gemfile`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are starting the server using C9's 'run' command. Instead try running your code with this in the C9 terminal (make sure you are in the correct directory):

```
rails s -b $IP -p $PORT
```

A Cloud9 popup should appear that you can click the link to view your code.

Comment: Thanks jdgray! It's so helpful to do it !

Comment: Glad I could be of some help! If this or any other answer has helped you solve your question please consider accepting it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to run the rails server

Run the rails server command and then preview running application

```
~/environment/hello_app (master) $ rails server
```

[image: Running the Rails server]